# Use a std::vector to initialize part of another std::vector

Tags: c++

Is there a way to "expand" a vector variable in an initialization list to achieve something to the effect of

```
std::vector<int> tmp1{1,1,2,3,5};
std::vector<int> tmp2{11,tmp1,99};
//tmp2 == {11,1,1,2,3,5,99}
```

I know it could be done with std::copy or insert. Was wondering if there was list-initialization way achieve that. something like `[11,*tmp1,99]` in python

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.  You will have to insert `11`, `tmp1` and `99` as separate operations.

Comment: If you read about [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), you can come up with something like `std::vector<int> tmp2{11, 99}; tmp2.insert(std::next(tmp2.begin()), tmp1.begin(), tmp1.end());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this solution you can have something close the the syntax you want.
(And yes some of the work will be done at runtime)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace details
{
// recursive part
template<typename type_t, typename arg_t, typename...  args_t>
void append_to_vector(std::vector<type_t>& vec, arg_t value, args_t&&... values)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_t, std::vector<type_t>>)
    {
        vec.insert(vec.end(), value.begin(), value.end());
    }
    else
    {
        vec.push_back(value);
    }

    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) > 0)
    {
        append_to_vector(vec, std::forward<args_t>(values)...);
    }
}
}

template<typename type_t, typename...  args_t>
std::vector<type_t> make_vector(args_t&&... values)
{
    std::vector<type_t> retval;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) > 0)
    {
        details::append_to_vector(retval, std::forward<args_t>(values)...);
    }
    return retval;
};

int main()
{
    auto tmp1 = make_vector<int>(1, 1, 2, 3, 5);
    auto tmp2 = make_vector<int>(11, tmp1, 99);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to create a `make_vector` variadic function template that checks if the current argument supports [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). If it supports `std::begin()`, use the `vector`'s `insert` member function, otherwise, use `emplace_back`. That should make it possible to make a vector from any container (with the correct `T`).

First, one type trait to check if the current argument supports `std::begin()` and one that checks if it supports [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). `std::size()` will be used to calculate how much space the final `vector` will need. Reserving space is often used to avoid reallocating space (and moving elements) when populating `vector`s when the final (or minimal) amount of elements is known - as it is in this case.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class has_begin {
    template<typename TT>
    static auto test(int) -> 
        decltype( std::begin(std::declval<const TT&>()), std::true_type() );

    template<typename>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool has_begin_v = has_begin<T>::value;
```

```
template<typename T>
class has_size {
    template<typename TT>
    static auto test(int) ->
        decltype( std::size(std::declval<const TT&>()), std::true_type() );

    template<typename>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool has_size_v = has_size<T>::value;
```

Then, the actual `make_vector` function template and helpers to calculate the actual size and determine what to do with one specific argument.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace detail {

template<class T, class Arg>
size_t make_vector_capacity(Arg&& arg) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>>) {
        // same type as in the vector, return 1
        return 1;
    } else if constexpr(has_size_v<Arg>) {
        // a container supporting std::size
        return std::size(arg);
    } else if constexpr(has_begin_v<Arg>) {
        // a container but not supporting std::size
        return std::distance(std::begin(arg), std::end(arg));
    } else {
        // fallback
        return 1;
    }
}

template<class T, class Arg>
void make_vector_helper(std::vector<T>& v, Arg&& arg) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>>) {
        // same type as in the vector, insert it as-is
        v.emplace_back(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    } else if constexpr(has_begin_v<Arg>) {
        // arg supports std::begin, use insert
        v.insert(v.end(), std::begin(arg), std::end(arg));
    } else {
        // fallback
        v.emplace_back(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
}
} // namespace detail
```

```
template<class T, class... Args>
std::vector<T> make_vector(Args&&... args) {
    std::vector<T> rv;

    // a fold expression to calculate the capacity needed:
    rv.reserve( (detail::make_vector_capacity<T>(args) + ...) );

    // a fold expression to call make_vector_helper for each argument
    (detail::make_vector_helper(rv, std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);

    return rv;
}
```

A usage example, mixing different containers and single values of `std::string`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    const std::string arr[] = {"3"s, "4"s};
    const std::vector vec{"5"s, "6"s, "7"s , "8"s};
    const std::list list{"9"s,"10"s};
    auto init = {"13"s, "14"s, "15"s};

    const auto tmp2 = make_vector<std::string>("1"s, "2"s, arr, vec, list,
                                               "11"s, "12"s, init );

    for(const auto& e: tmp2) std::cout << e <<' ';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6K5aKGddd)

Comment: This is more generic, liked the way it has been tackled.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible but you can make a helper that allows can do it:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Containerize MaybeContainer type if it not equal to T.
template<typename T, typename MaybeContainer>
using impl_containerize =  std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T,std::decay_t<MaybeContainer>>,std::array<T,1>,MaybeContainer>;

// Concatenate containers
template<typename Container,typename...Args>
Container impl_construct(Args&&...args){
    Container c;
    (c.insert(c.end(), std::begin(args), std::end(args)), ...);
    return c;
}

template<typename Container,typename...Args>
Container construct(Args&&...args){
    using T = typename Container::value_type;
    return impl_construct<Container, impl_containerize<T,Args>...>({std::forward<Args>(args)}...);
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> tmp1{1,3,5,7,9};
    const auto tmp2 = construct<std::vector<int>>(2,4,tmp1,6);
    for(const auto& e: tmp2){
        std::cout<<e<<' ';
    }
}
```

Output

```
2 4 1 3 5 7 9 6
```

Comment: Similar idea, different approach ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yep :) Yours is maybe be more optimal due to `push_back`, I hope the compiler can optimize my one-element array away.

Comment: This question was good fun to practice c++17 template metaprogramming on .  And I don't think anyone is going to notice the extra one-element array. The solution is still O(n)  :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer My favourite kind of questions here :) Definitely, on my screen you have to scroll right to see the array, nobody will do that :D